# unable to execute adb in Ubuntu. Downloaded file is meant for x86-64 while I have i686

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to use AndroidStudio, but when I hit the run button, I get an error message saying that it can't obtain a debug bridge. I checked the adb file under platform-tools using the `file` command and found that it is meant for x86-64, while I'm running i686. Do you know where I can get the adb file meant for 32-bits Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: seriously? This was asked more than a year ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip`](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip)
 is the last 32-bit version. Use that instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Android Studio aims to support only 64-bit systems.

I used it on 32-bit systems last year, and remember a warning explaining that 32-bit will not be supported in the long-term.

You can follow this "issue" [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866).