# Android Studio ADB not responding with adb-version

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Ten days ago, I had problem with starting ADB from Android Studio, and had this message `ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'`but ADB weren't in active processes. 
I have tried:

- Delete and install `platform-tools` with deleting everything in this folder
- Reinstall Android Studio and SDK
- ADB `kill-server` and `start-server`
- Delete `.android` folder
- Delete caches

And nothing have solved this problem, I must reinstall my OS and that works.
Now, ten days ago, I'm facing same problem and I tried everything again and nothing.

Can you help me?

I'm using Windows 10 and Android Studio 1.5.1 with stable version of SDK.
In addition, I have tried commands like `adb devices` from Cmd and it works.

**NOTE:** I have idea what is problem, when I type in Cmd some adb command(`adb devices`) it takes 5-6 seconds to respond, and probably this is reason why Android Studio recognize ADB not responding.

**EDIT:** I haven't found solution for problem yet, but I refresh Windows insted of reinstalling and it works again, but it consumes time for installing all apps again.

**SOLUTION:** I have found what is problem. My antivirus Avast! sometimes scans file and it takes 2-3 seconds and Android Studio recognized app not responding.  And Avast! doesn't show any info for scanning

Answer (score 0):

Your OS is 32bit or 64bit?
Some recent version of Android Studio inserts platform-tools with the 64bit architecture, if it's your case read here: [unable to execute adb in Ubuntu. Downloaded file is meant for x86-64 while I have i686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283851/unable-to-execute-adb-in-ubuntu-downloaded-file-is-meant-for-x86-64-while-i-hav)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading to Windows 10. Like you said, it was a problem with my Avast firewall. The [solution](http://rmarcejaeger.com/2016/04/30/solution-how-to-fix-android-studios-unable-to-obtain-result-of-adb-version-error/) was to **add the sdk and Android Studio paths to my firewall exception list** and after that it worked!