# Google's shipping 64-bit SDK stuff by default now?

Tags: android, linux, sdk, adb, x86-64

I'm just starting to use Android Studio on Linux, spent almost a year getting it working, yesterday I did some tutorials then did some downloads with sdk manager.  Now my ADB doesn't work anymore.  Big surprise, my ADB executable is now dated today, and fastboot, etc.  So I checked with the "file" utility and:

file adb
adb: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
BuildID[sha1]=90addc5e3980f6efab749c9032cc8d7ad60dfb94, not stripped

file fastboot
fastboot: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux
2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=f0fd57bfe0c22d4ba1e0b3e211441162066433b4, not stripped

file dmtracedump
dmtracedump: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux
2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=86871b6d114d9f8f9f0263d061cd9db8eb8886b7, not stripped

file sqlite3
sqlite3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,

### BuildID[sha1]=68c2ef312f09631815b20ecbc5dce2669e350807, not stripped

You mean to tell me Google can't afford to keep a 32-bit build machine?  I can't run 64 bit on my computers.  Maybe it was an accident.  This was apparently Platform-tools 23.1.  I had it working for 1 day, grrr.

Copied in a tarball of platform_tools 22.x from another machine, seems to be working so far.  I couldn't even bring up the emulator, that also uses ADB to communicate with it.

Comment: Hello sir, my respect to you but what exactly the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to execute adb in Ubuntu. Downloaded file is meant for x86-64 while I have i686](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283851/unable-to-execute-adb-in-ubuntu-downloaded-file-is-meant-for-x86-64-while-i-hav)

Comment: The problem is there's no warning that upgrading will break a working 32-bit machine, and downloading platform_tools 22 doesn't seem to be an option anymore.  My computers are all too old for 64 bit operating systems.  Luckily I had a copy.

Comment: `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip` is still 32bit

Answer (score 0):

Under *System Requirements* (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) you can find:

> Tested on Ubuntu® 14.04, Trusty Tahr (64-bit distribution capable of
>   running 32-bit applications).

If you want to keep compatibility to whatever your architecture and platform is perhaps you should use https://packages.debian.org/sid/android-tools-adb which may have older versions but perhaps enough to what you are trying to acieve.

Comment: That's true to a point.  32 bit's been deprecated for a while of course.  The upgrade recommended by SDK Manager took me from a working 32-bit ADB and Fastboot to a 64-bit version that I can't use.  I'm new to Android but I've been around unix and Linux for 20 years.  I had a copy on another machine from rooting a phone so I copied it to this one.  And I'm using Debian about 8.2, not Ubuntu.  I'm reluctant to trust any more of Google's upgrades.  All platform tools before 23 seem to be gone, at least from SDK Manager.