# Android ADB can not start on ubuntu 14.04 LTS or Cannot launch AVD in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Android ADB can not start on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It shows following error:

> Unable to detect adb version,  adb output
>   /home/k13/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:
>   /home/k13/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Android AVD cannot Launch 
given following error:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>   Output:
>   Android/sdk/tools/emulator: 1: Android/sdk/tools/emulator: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

### Android ADB can not start on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

[image]

### Cannot launch AVD in emulator

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to execute adb in Ubuntu. Downloaded file is meant for x86-64 while I have i686](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283851/unable-to-execute-adb-in-ubuntu-downloaded-file-is-meant-for-x86-64-while-i-hav)

Comment: #Alex 
ADB problems is solve but AVD Can not Start 
Given bellow Error's

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Android/sdk/tools/emulator: 1: /home/k13/Android/sdk/tools/emulator: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens with the Android Studio new update if your system is 32-bit.
You can downgrade this update, Follow these steps:

1.Download this arch. : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
2.Go to your Android SDK folder

3.Remove old /platform-tools

4.Insert downloaded from link above

Hope this help you.

Comment: adb is starting but still unable to start avd error /Android/sdk/tools/emulator: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: go through this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/534044/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated-when-attemping-to-r

Comment: I think updating emulator configuration will help you.

Comment: adding bellow line on the profile but error can not solve

export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true

Answer (score 2):

### export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true

### Alternative way to resolve this error

install **Genymotion** in your Ubuntu