# Android Studio not detected my usb device - ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Android device is not detected in android studio after updating it from 2.1.4 to 2.2.3 on Ubuntu, previously it was working fine. Even I tried with previous version still its not detecting.
I have already enabled usb debugging. I tried MTP and PTP too nothing works for me.

android device is connected to computer

```
bhanuchand@bhanuchand-X550CC:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 2717:1218  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Bus 003 is my device redmi 1s which doesn't have any description

adb device

```
bhanuchand@bhanuchand-X550CC:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
976fc0d9    device
```

it showing nothing
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeySY.png)

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: did you enable debugging in your phone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503064/android-adb-can-not-start-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-or-cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator
This helps me to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, I'm running studio on ubuntu 32-bit version. Android studio Developers stopped supporting 32-bit versions. To get it worked downgrade your build version to 21 or below in `gradle` and rebuild the project (download if it needed).

Answer (score 0):

install device driver on Ubuntu and restart the system..
make sure you select MTP is selected

Answer (score -1):

This command is to install the mainstream device driver, can not find the driver can also be manually added in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

`$ wget -S -O - http://source.android.com/source/51-android.rules | sed "s/<username>/$USER/" | sudo tee >/dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules; sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

Comment: Please explain your answers

Comment: See, I've already added vendor id of my device in android 51 rules and it worked fine then. Now its not detecting after updating it to 2.2.3 @cricket_007