# Android studio does not detect my phone but adb does from command line (linux)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm on a linux based on Debian OS, I have Android SDK and Android Studio installed. I can install app via command line with adb on my phone but, Android studio cannot detect my phone.

I only have this line in event log

```
4:56:09 PM Platform and Plugin Updates: The following component is ready to update: Android SDK Platform-tools
```

But, when I update the SDK Platform-tools, I got this event log error

```
Adb connection Error:EOF
    5:07:27 PM Connection attempts: 1
    5:07:28 PM Connection attempts: 2
    5:07:29 PM Connection attempts: 3
    5:07:30 PM Connection attempts: 4
    5:07:31 PM Connection attempts: 5
    5:07:32 PM Connection attempts: 6
    5:07:33 PM Connection attempts: 7
    5:07:34 PM Connection attempts: 8
    5:07:35 PM Connection attempts: 9
    5:07:36 PM Connection attempts: 10
    5:07:37 PM Connection attempts: 11
    5:07:37 PM '/usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
    5:07:37 PM adb restart attempts: 1
    5:07:37 PM /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1: /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    5:07:38 PM Connection attempts: 12
    5:07:38 PM '/usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
    5:07:38 PM adb restart attempts: 2
    5:07:38 PM /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1: /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    5:07:39 PM Connection attempts: 13
    5:07:39 PM '/usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
    5:07:39 PM adb restart attempts: 3
    5:07:39 PM /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1: /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    5:07:40 PM Connection attempts: 14
    5:07:40 PM '/usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
    5:07:40 PM adb restart attempts: 4
    5:07:40 PM /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1: /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    5:07:41 PM Connection attempts: 15
    5:07:41 PM '/usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
    5:07:41 PM adb restart attempts: 5
    5:07:41 PM /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1: /usr/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
    5:07:42 PM Connection attempts: 16
```

Even if I got that error log from Android Studio, I am able to run adb fine from command line.

Comment: Check android sdk tool path configured in android studio. Tools>Android>sdk manager

Comment: Have you added an android rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/##-android.rules?

Comment: Change the connection mode MTP to PTP

Comment: I have already configured Android sdk manager in Android studio

Comment: I don't know why the file ##-android.rules is but, I create it but the problem persist.

Comment: My usb connection mode was on sdcard, I changed it to PTP but, the problem persists. And the problem is not in connection mode. I think it's in Android studion

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to execute adb in Ubuntu. Downloaded file is meant for x86-64 while I have i686](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283851/unable-to-execute-adb-in-ubuntu-downloaded-file-is-meant-for-x86-64-while-i-hav)

Comment: No, it is not. That platform-tools(v. 23.0.1) downloaded link from that forum, is the same I have. I just went to the [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html#) and found that the new platform-tools(v. 23.1.0) is only for X64. It seems like Android will no longer support X86. But The update problem thing is solved but now, how can I fix the devices problem in Android studio.

Comment: So it's ok now. to run my app, I just generated signed apk, create a shell to automatically install the app to my phone or emulator.